# Centre text in ruby/libgosu

Tags: ruby, libgosu

I am trying to centre text in ruby/gosu. However all answers I have come across use deprecated methods. This is the code I've made from those answers. Any help on how to make it work with current versions?

```
if @track_listing < album.tracks.length
        track_display = Gosu::Image.from_text(self, tracks, Gosu.default_font_name, 50)
        track_display.draw_rot(750, 300, 0, center_x = 0.5, center_y = 0.5)
end
```

Comment: did you try these :https://apidock.com/ruby/String/center if you just want to centre text

Comment: How does that help centre text in a Gosu window?

Comment: https://github.com/gosu/gosu/wiki/ruby-tutorial#21-player--movement     
did you try with @image.draw_rot as given in the documentation and also "Note that draw_rot puts the center of the image at (x, y)"

Comment: That's for an image, I'm trying to do text. I have tried using the method draw_rot, but the method I used before it has been deprecated. Sorry if that wasn't clear. How do I create the text I want to use in draw_rot?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for [Font#draw_rel](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/gosu/gosu/Gosu/Font#draw_rel-instance_method)? In addition to that, you can measure the text with other methods and calculate yourself if that does not work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to put a TEXT in Window with GOSU is using FONT.

Initialize it

```
your_text = Gosu::Font.new(FONT_HEIGHT)
```

And then draw it

```
your_text.draw_text('HERE A TEXT', x, y, z)
```

You can center it using WINDOW height and width attribute.